# Date issue with rangepicker

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-recurse

I have this recursion code to pick dates in a rangepicker:

```
    recurse(
        () => cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-yearsListCell').invoke('text'),
        (n) => {
          if (!n.includes(year)) { //if year not found click on first button
            cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').first().click();
          }
          else
            if  (!n.includes(year).length < 0) {// if year not found after clicking on first button after recurce click on last btn
              cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').last().click();
            }
            cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-yearsListCell').contains(year).click(); //year is found click on it
        },
      {
        limit: 12,
      }
      );
```

The issue is that it is working when i am adding 2021-07-01 - 2023-05-01 as range but does not work if i add 2019-07-01 - 2023-05-01 as range. When the range is 2019-07-01 - 2023-05-01 when trying to add the second date it is still doing the first instead of last but it should do last as 2023 comes after 2019

Basically if it does not find the year in when clicking on first it should click on the last.

update:  i understand now why it works for 2021-07-01 - 2023-05-01 its because on the year picker this date is visible..If i need to before 2021 it just wont click on the btn first.

Any help please..There must be something i am not understanding.

updated with new code:

```
 const month = monthsShort[date.getMonth()];
  const day = date.getDate();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  recurse(
    () => cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-yearsListCell')
      .then(years => years.get().map(year => year.innerText.trim()),
    (yearsCurrentlyShowing) => {   // pass in a list of individual years from the panel

      // first make the texts into numbers since target year is a number
      const currentYears = yearsCurrentlyShowing.map(y => parseInt(y))

      // case 1 - target year is on this panel
      if (currentYears.includes(year)) {
        return true
      }

      // case 2 - target year is before years on the panel
      if (year < currentYears[0]) {
        // go backwards
        cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').first().click()
        return false
      }

      // case 3 - target year is after years on the panel
      if (year > currentYears[currentYears.length - 1]) {
        // go forwards
        cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').last().click()
        return false
      }
    }),
    {
      limit: 12,
    }
  );
```

fails with Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Comment: What is `!n.includes(year) < 0`  expected to do? Assuming that's a standard JS `includes()` , it should be returning a boolean, so that comparison doesn't seem intentional (Neither `true` or `false` will ever be `< 0`)

Comment: Yes i think !n.includes(year) < 0 is not correct..Normally if it does n does not include year it should return false but after clicking on first if it does not get the year it should go to last.

Comment: i have updated my question and now i am wondering if my recurse solution is good nor not for this scenario

Comment: 1- in your code still u use a wrong if expression. `!n.includes(year).length < 0` in else if statement does nothing. 

2- why do u use recurse here? just for conditional? if so i suggest you to have a look at  cypress if plugin, https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if?tab=readme-ov-file#multiple-commands

Comment: I think it would be easier to set the date that the test is working with using `cy.clock()`, then you can do it without recursion and if..else statements. For instance `cy.clock(new Date(2023, 6, 01))` then you have an exactly known number of clicks on `.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon` to get to year 2019, if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the code `if (!n.includes(year))` doesn't tell you if you need to go backward or forward in the year selection panel (i.e doesn't help decide if you need `.first().click()` or `.last().click()`).

When you select `cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-yearsListCell').invoke('text')` you get a single string containing all the **years** on the current selection panel.

So `if (!n.includes(year))` will tell you the required year isn't on that page, but to find which direction to go you might compare the list of currently displayed years (individual texts not one single text).

Something like:

```js
(yearsCurrentlyShowing) => {   // pass in a list of individual years from the panel

  // first make the texts into numbers since target year is a number
  const currentYears = yearsCurrentlyShowing.map(y => parseInt(y))

  // case 1 - target year is on this panel
  if (currentYears.includes(year)) {
    return true
  }

  // case 2 - target year is before years on the panel
  if (year < currentYears[0]) {
    // go backwards
    cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').first().click()
    return false
  }

  // case 3 - target year is after years on the panel
  if (year > currentYears[currentYears.length-1]) {
    // go forwards
    cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').last().click()
    return false
  }
}
```

To get the list of individual years on the current panel, you will need a different query for the first parameter to `recurse()`

```js
() => cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-yearsListCell')
        .then(years => years.get().map(year => year.innerText.trim())
```

---

Comment: Hello @Aladin Spaz, thank you.. I am getting the error, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') for the recurse()

Comment: Also to confirm my dates are in an array like this:
   [new Date('2019-07-01'),
      new Date('2023-07-05')]

Comment: I'll run a test, but the error you mention seems to indicate `years` is undefined - so it might be a typo.

Comment: ***my dates are in an array*** - it's not the range dates that I refer to, but the year values from `cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-yearsListCell').invoke('text')` that need to be converted to an array rather than a string. (My bad I did say "containing all the "dates" on the current selection panel" - that should read "containing all the **years** on the current selection panel"

Comment: My test worked ok - I also tested `2009` which is two steps backwards. The recurse function worked in both tests.

Comment: is it an issue with my variables?
  const month = monthsShort[date.getMonth()];
  const day = date.getDate();
  const year = date.getFullYear();

Comment: That seems ok to me - you can check each variable in the console to see it has the right value. I just hard-coded `const year = 2019` in my test as it's the recurse callbacks  that need changing (to get forward/backward logic right).

Comment: i have updated my question with how i wrote it just in case i messed it up somewhere.Can you please check?

Comment: There's a bracket missing, should be `.then(years => years.get().map(year => year.innerText.trim())),` - three closing brackets. I was going to mention it then it slipped my mind. Your VSCode should already show you that error, but maybe because it's indside `recurse()` the problem is obscured.